# CSS not being applied in iOS app

Tags: ios, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

We are writing a Cordova/jQuery Mobile app, and coming across an issue with iOS (both 6 and 7). The problem is that CSS is sometimes in iOS is not being applied, even though it should be. The problem is both in the emulator and device itself.

For instance:

- A `background-color: red` is displayed as white.
- An element with `overflow:scroll` (both with and without `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`) cannot be scrolled.

It's not an inheritance issue - the same CSS works fine in desktop FF, Chrome, Safari, IE and in Android. It also works fine using Safari remote inspection - the style won't be displayed initially, but simply un-checking and then re-checking the property in the Safari developer tools makes it work normally !

I have not be able to isolate what causes this problem, but when it happens it happens consistently. Is there a fix for this problem ?

Comment: This sounds some kind of rendering issue. What kind of other CSS the section with background-color: red; is having? In addition, have you added also -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; for scrollable content? Paste some code, please.

Comment: I wish I could, but unfortunately I can't reproduce it simply outside of our project as of yet (trying though). I was hoping someone else had seen this issue before and knew about it. Other CSS, yes we have -webkit-overflow-scrolling already and jQuery mobile also adds a lot of CSS by itself which complicates things. Simply unchecking and re-checking any property in the dev tools fixes the issue - makes it very difficult to track down what could be causing it!

Comment: for overflow scroll try `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` or add `html { overflow: hidden; }`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine for iOS6. You can try using hexadecimal code for background color and add
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; for smooth scrolling.

For iOS7 the bellow link may help you.

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review